# how to retrieve data from multiple table into a single table

Tags: sql-server

I am having 3 tables **Book Master**, **Category Master**, **Subcategory Master**. In my **Book Master** table, column `CategoryName` have value from **Category Master**'s `ID` column. And `SubcategoryName` column in **Book Master** have `ID` columns value from **Subcategory Master**.

Table structure of the 3 tables:

**Book Master**

```
Oid             uniqueidentifier,
BookName        nvarchar(100),
CategoryName    uniqueidentifier,
SubCategoryName uniqueidentifier
```

**Category Master**

```
Oid             uniqueidentifier,
CategoryName    nvarchar(100)
```

**Subcategory Master**

```
Oid             uniqueidentifier,
CategoryName    uniqueidentifier,
SubCategoryName nvarchar(100)
```

I am working on one windows application,in that I have to show top 5 books from each category of book.Now I am having 10 records in table and I have used the following query to display the books on form.

```sql
select BM.BookName ,BM.BookImage,CM.CategoryName,SCM.SubCategoryName
from BookMaster BM,CategoryMaster CM,SubCategoryMaster SCM 
where BM.CategoryName=CM.Oid and BM.SubCategoryName=SCM.Oid 
order by CM.CategoryName
```

this query gives me all 10 records. But, this query is fine when records in table are less. But when records goes on increasing, It will be difficult to show all records. For this reason, I want to show Top 5 books from each category.

I have tried it with group by clause

```sql
select top 5 BM.BookName ,BM.BookImage,CM.CategoryName,SCM.SubCategoryName
from BookMaster BM,CategoryMaster CM,SubCategoryMaster SCM 
where BM.CategoryName=CM.Oid and BM.SubCategoryName=SCM.Oid
group by CM.CategoryName
```

but it gives me error saying,

> Column 'BookMaster.BookName' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Suggest me any solution for this.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Write a function that takes CategoryName and returns top 5 books for that category as a table
Then use T SQL Apply to print your desired result

More more details  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156%28v=sql.105%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
WITH CategoryCTE AS (
    SELECT 
        BookName,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
            PARTITION BY CategoryName
            ORDER BY CategoryName DESC
        ) AS CTE_Order
    FROM BookMaster
)
SELECT bm.BookName, cm.CategoryName, scm.SubCategoryName
FROM 
    CategoryCTE 
    INNER JOIN BookMaster bm ON CategoryCTE.BookName = bm.BookName
    INNER JOIN CategoryMaster cm ON bm.CategoryName = cm.Oid
    INNER JOIN SubCategoryMaster scm ON bm.SubCategoryName = scm.Oid
WHERE CategoryCTE.CTE_Order < 6
GROUP BY cm.CategoryName, scm.SubCategoryName, bm.BookName
```

Comment: thanks for reply.I got the output by using the query given by you.

Answer (score 0):

Please look over this link for solution

http://sqlzoo.net/howto/source/z.dir/err979/sqlserver

While using group by clause in query you have to specify the selected list of columns in select query in group clause, Otherwise its showing error what you get